# How do I type accents and other special symbols on the spanish stack exchange?

Tags: soporte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy way to type accented characters](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/easy-way-to-type-accented-characters)

Sorry, I'm very new to the community and I want to learn effective strategies for typing special characters such as accent & tilde marks, and special punctuation marks.